# Як перекласти слово rebel?

Tags: переклад, from-english

Я думаю що *повстанець*, але мені вперто говорять що *заколотник* ближче. Як перекладати наприклад *pro-Russian rebels in Ukraine* і *Українська Повстанська Армія*? В другому випадку вживають слово *insurgent* а не *rebel*.

Comment: Ласкаво просимо до сайту Ukrainian Language.SE! Наші критерії якості вимагають, щоб запитання про переклад містило: пояснення **своїми словами** іншомовного слова, а також **контекст**, в якому автор збирається використовувати перекладене слово. Також, варто пояснити, чим са́ме не підходять знайдені варіанти. Запитання, які не відповідають цим умовам, змушують інших «вгадувати», чого саме хоче автор, і тому заважають надавати точні відповіді. Будь ласка, перегляньте сторінки [tour], [ask] а також [«Якими мають бути гарні запитання і відповіді»](http://meta.ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/5/).

Comment: Це залежить від контексту, я думаю. Наведіть, будь ласка, контекст.

Comment: Українська Повстанська Армія, pro-Russian rebel on Donbass, тобто як мені перекладати повстанець і rebel?

Comment: Вам треба цей коментар перенести в ваше запитання, але раз ви вже прийняли відповідь, то я б радив вам оформити нове запитання. Але тут буде важко вам допомогти, бо це значною мірою політичне питання. Наші ЗМІ називають їх бойовиками, два роки тому терористами. В Росії їх мабуть називають якось інакше. Тому вам треба вибрати для перекладу те слово, яке ще й відповідає вашому світогляду.

Comment: Так мені людина вперто люто доводить що повстанець то не rebel, тому вже і скотилося в політику — http://tereveni.org/topic/30617/page__pid__888050__st__60#entry888050, за це і весь сир-бор, вже сарказмом відповідаю...

Comment: Я не думаю, що слово insurgent застаріло. Останнім часом вийшло декілька фільмів з такою назвою. І урівнювати УПА з ДНР/ЛНР не коректно. УПА спиралось на широку підтримку місцевого населення, ніхто йому зброю не постачав, після того як туди прийшли совєти, воно ще 10 років боролось без будь-якої допомоги ззовні. А ДНР/ЛНР якби не підтримка з Росії закінчились би за 1 місяць. Вони б без неї і не почались.

Comment: Я не урівнюю, але є загальноприйняті назви як от Ukrainian Insurgent Army чи pro-Russian rebels in Ukraine, і є значення слів insurgent і rebel, відповідно потрібно перекладати маючи на увазі не те що я думаю про це, а те що думали ті що це писали, інакше це буде не переклад а переказ тексту, вірно? Ну я не перекладач і мої знання мов то печаль, ну все ж таки бачу де і коли вживаються слова...

Comment: І не слово *insurgent* застаріло а слово *інсургент*, що потрапило в українську мові ззовні.

Comment: Ось чому не треба швидко відповідати на низькоьакісні запитаньа, а то каша виходить. Красше створити нового нормального запитаньа, а сього закрити.

Comment: Мені здається, можна cпитати на [ELL](//ell.stackexchange.com) чи [English](//english.stackexchange.com), у чому різниця між _insurgent_ і _rebel_. По-моєму, по-перше, _insurgent_ — іменник і прикметник, а _rebel_ — іменник і дієслово (_rebellious_ буде прикметник), по-друге, _insurgent_ тлумачать як учасник групової дії, тоді як для _rebel_ це необов'язково (_rebel_ може бути одинаком); але загалом _insurgent_ і _rebel_ тлумачать майже як синоніми, а що _УПА_ передають як _insurgent_ — це радше традиція (а не наслідок різниці значень), хто перший як написав, так і повелося. Але я непевен.

Comment: Так а як перекладати, тільки перекладати а не переказувати Russian backend rebels on Donbass?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Загальний народний англійсько-український словник 2010–](https://e2u.org.ua/s?w=rebel&dicts=all&highlight=on&filter_lines=on)

> rebel
>     1. [reb(ə)l] n
>       1) повста́нець (повста́нка), заколо́тник, бунтівни́к, бунта́р, ворохо́бник; заст. крамо́льник

[Українсько-англійський словник 1955р. (К. Андрусишин, Я. Крет)](https://e2u.org.ua/s?w=rebel&dicts=all&highlight=on&filter_lines=on)

> **бунта́р (-ря́) m, бунта́рка (-ки)** f rioter, rebel, mutineer
>   **інсурґе́нт [інсурге́нт] (-та)** m insurgent, rebel
>   **повста́нець (-нця)** m insurgent, rebel;

В [словнику синонімів](https://uk.worldwidedictionary.org/%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%86%D1%8C) обидва слова подаються, як синоніми.

> ЗАКОЛО́ТНИК (учасник заколоту), БУНТІВНИ́К, БУНТА́Р, ПУТЧИ́СТ
>   ПОВСТА́НЕЦЬ (учасник повстання), ПОВСТА́ЛИЙ, ІНСУРГЕ́НТ заст.

Все залежить від контексту, в якому ви будете використовувати слово.

Comment: пропоную ще з тої самої сторінки процитувати словник Андрусишина, Крета, який користується більшою повагою, ніж просто народний. Ще є ось таке посилання: https://www.yenotes.com/uk/?q=rebel&from_lang=en&to_lang=uk

Comment: Слово бунтар пішло від "бунт" по ідеї, але бунт це трішки менш організована штука ніж повстання, а у визначенні rebellion чітко написано про організацію, тому вважаю бунтар(ка) недоречним. Академічне визначення заколоту також дещо віддаляє його від повстання в стихійну сторону, отже найкраще для перекладу rebel в більшості випадків це повстанець(ка). В даному, конкретному випадку, як-раз саме так, і контекст тут вірний думаю.

Comment: https://e2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F&dicts=all&highlight=on&filter_lines=on — тут Андрусишин для повстання також є, там rebellion.

Answer (score -1):

[Гугл перекладач](https://translate.google.com/?hl=uk#view=home&op=translate&sl=en&tl=uk&text=rebel) дає варіанти "повстанець","бунтівник", а ще навіть "конфедерат". Слово "rebel" не є новим, тому я гадаю, що і в інших словник переклад буде таким же.

Сумніватися між "повстанцем" та "заколотником" не потрібно, бо обидва слова є в СУМі:

**[Повстанець](http://sum.in.ua/s/povstanecj)**:

> Учасник повстання, заколоту.

**[Заколотник](http://sum.in.ua/s/zakolotnyk)**:

> 1. Учасник заколоту (у 1 знач.); бунтівник.

Отже ви можете перекласти це слово як "бутнівник", "бунтар", "повстанець", "заколотник".

Comment: перепрошую, але посилання на ґуґл-перекладач, як єдине посилання (пов'язане саме з перекладом) у відповіді, навіть якщо є пояснення, чому йому можна довіряти, - дуже недобра якість відповіді. Такі відповіді завжди буду мінусувати. Є анґл-укр-анґл словники навіть онлайн непогані. Немає причини їх іґнорувати й користуватися машинним перекладом.