# Переклад "сыр-бор"

Tags: переклад, етимологія, from-russian, фразеологізми

В одному з коментарів до питання [Як перекласти слово rebel?](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/5498/%D0%AF%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE-rebel) є такий вираз - "за це і весь сир-бор, вже сарказмом відповідаю.."

Цікавить саме слово "сир-бор". В словниках його не знайшла, лише російську статтю в [Вікісловнику](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%81%D1%8B%D1%80-%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80) де вказано, що вживається в значенні переполоху.

Чи правильно вживати саме такий переклад "сир-бор"? Також цікавить походження слова "Сыр-бор".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Московське *«сыр-бор {разгорелся}»* [походить](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%81%D1%8B%D1%80-%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80) від фразеологізму, який означає «з-за однієї сосни {увесь} сирий бір розгорівся». Тобто, **з-за дрібнички розгорілася суперечка**.
Бір — це ліс, здебільшого сосновий.
А сирий — тому що росте на сирому місці, на болотах.

Відповідно, дослівно — **сир-бір**. Це словосполучення навіть намагаються вживати:

> [*Сир-бір в «Іванівському борі»*](http://pryroda.in.ua/zapzf/syr-bir-v-ivanivskomu-bori/)
>
> На території ландшафтного заказника «Іванівський бір», розташованого в межах міста Енергодару, вже другий рік триває масове знищення лісу й водних об’єктів. Під сокиру пішли **заплавні ліси** та 90-річний **сосновий бір**.

Answer (score 4):

В [Словнику Савченко](http://univer.nuczu.edu.ua/tmp_metod/1047/%D1%E0%E2%F7%E5%ED%EA%EE%20%CB.%20%C3._%D0%EE%F1%B3%E9%F1%FC%EA%EE-%F3%EA%F0%E0%BF%ED%F1%FC%EA%E8%E9%20%F1%EB%EE%E2%ED%E8%EA%20%F1%EB%EE%E2%EE%F1%EF%EE%EB%F3%F7%E5%ED%FC.%20%D2%F0%F3%E4%ED%EE%F9%B3%20%EF%E5%F0%E5%EA%EB%E0%E4%F3.pdf) (431 ст.) є переклад:

> "**сыр-бор** разгоревшийся" - "**буча**, що зчинилася"

В [СУМі](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=6253&page=229) є це слово:

> БУ́ЧА, і, жін.
>
> 1. Великий крик, галас, тривога.
> 2. Сварка, колотнеча.
>      Битва, бійка або заколот.
>
> **Збива́ти, зчиня́ти бу́чу**; (1) Зчиня́лася (здійма́лася, збива́лася і
>   т. ін.) / зчини́лася (здійня́лася, зби́лася і т. ін.) бу́ча: а)
>   **починалася сварка, колотнеча**. На другий день, після появи цього
>   вовкуватого Санька, раним-рано в камері зчинилась велика буча (І.
>   Багряний); б) починалася битва, бійка, заколот. Його займали хмари –
>   ся неспокійна небесна людність, за якою він стежив .. Часом здіймались
>   там бучі, народні повстання (М. Коцюбинський).

До речі, мені здається, що слово галас також може бути хорошим варіантом перекладу.

Сам вислів походить від російського "сырой сосновый лес" (в російському [Вікісловнику](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%81%D1%8B%D1%80-%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80#%D0%AD%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%8F) про це написано більше).